# echo "Sale" on woocommerce product page before product title if the product category is "store-pickup"

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Need help, I want to echo "sale" on the woocommerce product page on top of product title if the product is on the "store-pickup" product category.

Tried using the below code, but WordPress throws an error

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_store_pickup', 1 );
      function show_store_pickup() {
        global $product; 
     if (is_product_category( 'store-pickup' )) { 
      echo "Sale!";  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follows code -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_store_pickup', 1 );
function show_store_pickup() {
    global $product; 
    if ( has_term( 'store-pickup', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) 
        echo __( "Sale!", "text-domain" );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with "woocommerce_before_single_product_summary" hook. that might be help you. also check the result of is_product_category() is coming properly or not.

Comment: it says "this site is experiencing technical difficulties"

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_store_pickup', 1 );
      function show_store_pickup() {
        global $product; 
     if (is_product_category( 'store-pickup' )) { 
      echo "Sale!";  
}
}
try this

Comment: you forgot to add closing bracket.

Comment: Ok now it doesnt throw any errors but it doesnt echo anything.

Comment: might be not go in to if condition check for function you use.